# How can I delete duplicate rows with rank function in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am trying to delete duplicate rows with rank function, table is having 3 columns name, id and email and id can have duplicates which I am trying to remove and using below query -

```
delete 
    d
from 
    duplicates d
    inner join (
 select name,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id DESC) AS RowNumberWithinDuplicateSet
 from duplicates
  ) x on d.id = x.id



delete 
    d
from 
    duplicates d
    inner join (
 select Id,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId, OrderAmount ORDER BY Id DESC) AS RowNumberWithinDuplicateSet
 from duplicates
 where 
            OrderDate = '4/20/2020'
 ) x on d.id = x.id
```

Comment: You're wasting people's time by tagging 4 different DBMSs, because every dbms does this in a dramatically different way.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle PL/SQL, you can use rowid, along with rank to delete duplicate rows.

```
CREATE TABLE ranktesting
(
   id      VARCHAR2 (15),
   name    VARCHAR2 (15),
   email   VARCHAR2 (20)
);

INSERT INTO ranktesting
  VALUES   ('1', 'name', 'email');

INSERT INTO ranktesting
  VALUES   ('2', 'name', 'email');

INSERT INTO ranktesting
  VALUES   ('1', 'name', 'email');

INSERT INTO ranktesting
  VALUES   ('1', 'name', 'email');

INSERT INTO ranktesting
  VALUES   ('3', 'name', 'email');

INSERT INTO ranktesting
  VALUES   ('2', 'name', 'email');

commit;
```

Now execute following query and it will delete duplicate rows from table.

```
DELETE FROM   ranktesting
      WHERE   ROWID NOT IN
                    (SELECT   min_rowid
                       FROM   (  SELECT   MIN (ROWID) AS min_rowid,
                                          COUNT (ranking)
                                   FROM   (SELECT   ROWID,
                                                    id,
                                                    name,
                                                    email,
                                                    RANK () OVER (ORDER BY id)
                                                       ranking
                                             FROM   ranktesting)
                               GROUP BY   ranking));
```